# How to read file from Blob storage using scala to spark

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, blob

I have a piece of scala code that works locally

```
val test = "resources/test.csv"

val trainInput = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .load(train)
  .cache
```

However when i try to run it on azure, spark by submitting the job, and adjusting the following line:

```
val test = "wasb:///tmp/MachineLearningScala/test.csv"
```

It doesn't work. How do i reference files in blob storage in azure using scala? This should be straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sbt add this dependency to built.sbt

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "2.7.3"
```

For maven add the dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To read the files from blob storage you need to define the file system to be used in the underlying Hadoop configurations.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.yourAccount.blob.core.windows.net", "yourKey ")
```

And read the `csv` file as

```
  val path = "wasb[s]://BlobStorageContainer@yourUser.blob.core.windows.net"
  val dataframe = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv(path + "/tmp/MachineLearningScala/test.csv")
```

[here](https://sktechie.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/how-to-data-from-azure-blob-storage-with-apache-spark/) is the example
Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks! Thats brilliant. I will try and implement now.